# Bash or Python or Awk to match and modify files

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a set of 10000 files c1.dat ... c10000.dat. Each of these files contains a line which starts with @ and contains a string with spaces specific for this file, lije c37  7.379 6.23.

I have another set of 10000 files kind of determined_cXXX_send.dat (where XXX goes from 1 to 10000). Each of these files has only one line. Each line is of thsis type:

_1   1   3456.000000  -21   0  -98.112830  -20.326192

What I would like to do is, for each number XXX (between 1 to 10000), get from the cXXX.dat file the string like c37  7.379 6.23 , and add it in the file determined_cXXX_send.dat to the beginning of the file so I get:

c37  7.379 6.23 _1   1   3456.000000  -21   0  -98.112830  -20.326192

I tried with both bash and python but got no good solution.

What would be the best approach?

thanks

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear, but certainly Python, and maybe AWK are well equipped to handled this type of things...  Why was there "No good solution" in your first attempt with Python?

Comment: Actually both approaches seem more than doable. Bash with grep and ed would work. Python code certainly shouldn't pose much of a problem.

Comment: "I tried with both bash and python but got no good solution." What does this mean?  They didn't work?  Perhaps you should close this question and post the code that didn't work, along with the actual error messages, and ask for specific help with a specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you could do something like that

```
# loop on all the files
for num in range(1,1000):

    cfile = open ( 'c%u.dat'%num, mode='r')

    # find the specific line
    for line in cfile:
        if line[0]=='@':

            # open the determined file and add the line
            dfile = open( 'determined_c%u_send.dat'%num, mode='a')
            dfile.write( line[1:-1] )
            dfile.close()

    cfile.close()
```

It's untested, but it should work

EDIT: I realized you wanted to add the line at the beginning of the determined_cXXX_send.dat, not at the end.

So, based on Dennis Williamson's answer, I can also propose the following bash code

```
for i in {1..2}
do
    mv "determined_c${i}_send.dat" "temp.out"
    cat c1.dat | grep @ | tr -d "@" >  "determined_c${i}_send.dat"
    cat temp.out >> "determined_c${i}_send.dat"
done
rm temp.out
```

Comment: I think it would append the @ string to the target, whereas OP wanted to have it prepended... Easily fixable, though.

Comment: Using `cat` and `>>` will put a newline between the lines instead of having their contents on the same line. Also, at least one useless use of `cat`: `grep` can accept filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A language basically made for processing text: [Perl!](http://www.perl.org/)

Comment: "Learn a new language, and I won't bother to show you the one-liner that will do this"?

Answer (score 1):

If each of the two types of files only has one line:

```
for i in {1..10000}
do
    paste "c${i}.dat" "determined_c${i}_send.dat" > c${i}.out && 
    mv "c{$i}.out" "determined_c${i}_send.dat"
done
```

**Edit:**

```
for i in {1..10000}
do
    line=$(grep -o "^c${i}.*")
    line="${line#@*}"
    read data < determined_c${i}_send.dat
    echo "$line $data" > c${i}.out &&
    mv "c{$i}.out" "determined_c${i}_send.dat"
done
```

Comment: I thought he just wanted the one line.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in Python should be pretty trivial. It's probably possible in awk, but sounds a bit too complicated to be fun. It's surely is possible in bash, but programming in bash is for masochists.

I'd go with Python, of the given options, although Perl and Ruby are good options too if you know them.

Answer (score 0):

if "c37 7.379 6.23" is constant, then there's no need to grab this string from cXXX.dat files. But i am guessing this string is dynamic ,and it comes after @., so you can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in c{1..1000}.dat
do
    if [ -e "$file" ];then
        tag=${file%.dat}
        while read -r line
        do
            case "$line" in
                @*)
                    mystring=${line##@};;
            esac
        done < "$file"
        if [ -e "determined_${tag}_send.dat" ]; then
            while read -r line
            do
                echo "$mystring $line"
            done < "determined_${tag}_send.dat" > temp
            mv temp "determined_${tag}_send.dat"
        fi
    fi
done
```

output

```
$ cat c1.dat
@ c37 7.379 6.23

$ cat determined_c1_send.dat
_1 1 3456.000000 -21 0 -98.112830 -20.326192

$ ./shell.sh
$ cat determined_c1_send.dat
 c37 7.379 6.23 _1 1 3456.000000 -21 0 -98.112830 -20.326192
```